# Deleting lines by matching 3rd and 4th character only

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I am running a script that fetches me the data as given below,

```
1400d2b8
1f4d1e2507
1200781e
```

As you can see the 3rd and 4th character is `0` in line 1 and line 3. I am trying to write a single line script that prints the line except the lines containing `00`. In this case it should only print `1f4d1e2507`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways, e.g.,

```
awk '/^..00/{ next; }{ print; }' < mydata
sed '/^..00/d' < mydata
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can do that:

```
grep -v '^..00' inputfile
```